# Functions Filter Question

Tags: functions, filters

Why doesnt he input "$meinungen" ?

```
    add_filter('wpseo_set_title', 'wpseo_set_title_callback');
$meinungen = Test;
function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
    if (is_single()) {
        return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ' '. $input . '';
    }
    // return default
    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for Variable scope.

***A variable declared within a function has a LOCAL SCOPE and can only be accessed within that function***

***A variable declared outside a function has a GLOBAL SCOPE and can only be accessed outside a function:***

```
$meinungen = Test; // is in global scope
function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
if (is_single()) {
    return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ' '. $input . ''; // now $meinungen local variable which you don not assign value.
}
// return default
return $input; }
```

to call the value just put global with in function

```
function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
if (is_single()) {
   global $meinungen;
    return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ' '. $input . '';
}
// return default
return $input;
```

}